# How to stop restarting node.js server when particular file changes

Tags: node.js

Im using a package called "sp-pnp-node". Whenever Im running this file, new "private.json" file would create on the root folder.If I run this file again and again private.json file getting overwriting. So my node server got restarting everytime.

What i need is, is there any way to prevent restart node.js server when this file private.js getting save?.

Comment: how are you running your node server, are you using eg.`node app.js` or some other package like 'nodemon' or 'supervisor'?

Comment: Im using nodemon

Comment: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#automatic-re-running if you check here nodemon re-runs the application automatically if there is a change if you really don't want your app to restart just use node or framework like express

Comment: You can also use pm2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this config to your `package.json`, just add a directory or a file pattern to `nodemonConfig` in your `package.json` to ignore them. So, whenever there are any changes in the directory or file pattern that is ignored `nodemon` won't restart your server.

**Sample package.json**

```
{
    "name": "nodemon",
    "homepage": "http://nodemon.io",
    "...": "... other standard package.json values",
    "nodemonConfig": {
                        "ignore": ["*.json"]
                     }
}
```

take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#packagejson) for more information.